# Getting data from signed S3 URL giving: `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present`

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors

Been messing around with the Cors settings on my S3 bucket for a few hours now and figure it's time to ask for help. I'm trying to load some data from a signed URL I generate on my backend and display it in a react app. Everything I've tried on the frontend seems to yield the same result: `blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Here's my Cors configuration in S3:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Note: simply pasting the signed URL into chrome downloads my data just fine, and making the call in postman is the same. For some reason CORS only gives me issues if I make the call through my react app. All help much appreciated!

Comment: It only fails in React because CORS is only 'activated' in some context, like from a JavaScript script running on a web-page (and not JS running in Node). It is an opt-in protocol see https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/ : "User agents commonly apply same-origin restrictions to network requests. _These restrictions prevent a client-side Web application_ running from one origin from obtaining data retrieved from another origin.. _The user agent validates_ that the value and origin of where the request originated match." (The error is thrown _from_ the JavaScript request..)

Comment: So, in Postman, verify that the headers are indeed present [or not]. Specify whatever Origin header is sent by the browser. Also see the headers sent in the Developer Tools.

Comment: Ah yes, it looks like the headers are not present in Postman. 

Do you see anything wrong with my S3 cors policy above / should this not be sufficient to add them?

Comment: even I was facing the same issue when trying to do direct request to the signed URL from the UI. Finally created a file upload api in express and handling the s3 upload from Node side instead of React side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it's been resolved. The problem came down to the fact that the 'Origin' header in the request was being left blank and therefore preflight test returned fail regardless of the `<AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>`.

For anyone suffering the same issue, I suggest you look at network tab and make sure the correct request headers are present.